# What's the fastest way to install and set up TYPO3 locally?

Tags: typo3, ddev

I want to install and set up TYPO3 on my local machine. What's the best practice and fastest way to do so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For running TYPO3 on a local machine you need a web server running on your machine.

This can be done in different ways:

1. Native Web Server, PHP and database on a Linux based machine
2. Virtual Machine (VirtualBox, VMWare, Parallels, etc.)
3. Vagrant
4. Docker

Currently the fastest way to a "non power user" in my opinion is ddev.
ddev is a user-friendly possibility to run a perfect environment for TYPO3 on a docker base. It runs on Linux, Mac and Windows (minimum version 10, hyper-v recommended) and it brings all technologies you need for best experience.

1. Install Docker and ddev, see https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
2. Create a folder for your installation, e.g. `~/Websites/my-website/` or `C:\Websites\my-website\` and go into it.
3. Run `ddev config` and set these three options in the dialog:
4. Project name (default is your folder name): Whatever you like
5. Docroot location: `public` and say yes for creating
6. Project type: `typo3`
7. Run `ddev start` to start the Docker containers and add your root password to set the hosts entry (for accessing it via local domain)
8. Run `ddev composer create typo3/cms-base-distribution ^9` and say yes for overwriting
9. Run `ddev config` again and just hit enter for every dialog to create a file which provides the DB credentials for your TYPO3 installation
10. Run `ddev exec vendor/bin/typo3cms install:setup --no-interaction --admin-user-name=admin --admin-password=password --site-setup-type=site`

That's all, you have a running TYPO3 instance on your local machine.
You can access it by using `<project-name>.ddev.site` in your browser, in our example it should be http://my-website.ddev.site. To get into the TYPO3 backend you only need to put the credentials `admin:password` on http://my-website.ddev.site/typo3.

For troubleshooting go to:

- https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/troubleshooting/
- https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/Troubleshooting/Index.html
- https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ContributionWorkflowGuide/Appendix/SettingUpTypo3Ddev.html

Comment: just tried your tutorial, works like a charm. only difference was the url is not <project-name>.ddev.local it was <project-name>.ddev.site | maybe you can update your answer

Comment: @oiBio Thanks, I changed it. In earlier versions it was `.local`, but in the meantime it changed.